# definition function button javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code in JavaScript; I have one PieChart that gets data from the datasource. Now I want to add one button in my page that when I click it I can see my PieChart.

I want to define `function draw` in my button.

**HTML:**

```
<input id="drawChart" type="button" value="click me" ">
<script type="text/javascript" src="google.com/jsapi"></script>;
<script src="{{=URL('static','js/XXX/code/XXXX.js')}}"></script> 
<div id="reportingContainer"></div>
```

---

```
!function($) {

    function getTable() {
      $.ajax({
              dataType: 'json',         
              type: 'GET',
              url: 'call/json/mytables',
              xhrFields: {
                         withCredentials: true
                },
              success: function(response) {
                  sendQuery(response[0]);
              },
          });   
        }


    $("#drawChart").click( function () {
        ?????????????????????????????
    });



    function sendQuery(cityName) {
        // You can manipulate the variable response
        // Success!  
      var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://localhost:8080/XXXXX-datasource/datasource?table='+cityName);
      // Optional request to return only column C and the sum of column B, grouped by C members.
      query.setQuery('select zone_name, sum(cost) group by zone_name');
      // Send the query with a callback function.
      query.send(drawChart);

    }
    function initialize() {
            var $newDiv = $('<div>').attr('id','chart_div');
            $('#reportingContainer').append($newDiv);
  // Replace the data source URL on next line with your data source URL.
  // Specify that we want to use the XmlHttpRequest object to make the query.
           getTable();
    }  
     function drawChart(response) {
         if (response.isError()) {
         alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
         return;
    }   
         var data = response.getDataTable();
         var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};
         var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
         chart.draw(data, options);
    }   

}(jQuery);
```

Comment: What does getTable() return?

Comment: It return, the names of table that one user  can be connect with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `getTable()` is correct function to call the pie-chart means then try the below

```
$("#drawChart").on('click', function () {
        getTable();  //?????????????????????????????
    });
```

calling the `getTable` will take you to the `drawChart`.

**Updates:**

Since there is an ID attached to div, you can try like this

```
function initialize() {
            var $newDiv = $('<div>').attr('id','chart_div');            
            $('#reportingContainer').append($newDiv);

            $($newDiv).hide();  //hide the div here

  // Replace the data source URL on next line with your data source URL.
  // Specify that we want to use the XmlHttpRequest object to make the query.
           getTable();
    }
```

and show it on button click

```
$("#drawChart").on('click', function () {
       $('#chart_div').show(); //If it is visible hide it or vice versa
    });
```

Incase you want to go for [**.toggle()**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
$("#drawChart").on('click', function () {
       $('#chart_div').toggle(); //If it is visible hide it or vice versa
    });
```

Comment: <input id="drawChart" type="button" value="click me" ">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="{{=URL('static','js/probayes/code/reporting.js')}}"></script>

<div id="reportingContainer"></div>

Comment: @user225049 I think you should have seen the placeholder in comments textbox saying **"if it is a code edit your question"**

Comment: @user225049 where are you calling the `intialize()` no sign of that.  Also your html code has some bugs, you need to nake it clear. remove unnecessary " in it

Comment: @user225049 Are you getting the datachart first?

Comment: @user225049 sorry it was not data chart, "drawChart".  1. are you able to see the pie chart?  2.what about your `initailize()` method.  How are you calling?

Comment: @user225049 Oh, in which element are you referencing? means Is the piechart is within a div(if yes do you hv id or class in it?)

Comment: yes, piechart is within a div. i referencing in  function initialize()

Comment: merci @@user225049 it was so good, i understand the first method but the second method no ....   thanks

Comment: @user225049 if you don't understand you're free to ask :)  check this fiddle you will get idea http://jsfiddle.net/8hsKt/2/

Comment: @user225049 I'm glad I was able to help.